# How to display overlay on window using php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, overlay, disable-link

I have to disable website links all. if i place any overlay on website but it is not the right solution because we can remove that overlay using firebug or any browser tools...so is there any possible to freeze the site with out any actions...

Thanks,
Murali

Comment: Remove all the ``href``s?

Comment: no i have subscriptions. so user can login into website after subscriptions ends. but we have to block all activities until he subscribe again. so i have subscription popup. but using firebug tool we can disable popup. i don't need like this. total functions will block

Comment: Okay, in other words: You want to force the user to subscribe to use anything on your website? If so, why don't you make your content available only after being logged in?

Answer (score 0):

if you using jquery you can disable link action as follow

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('a').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Basically  `e.preventDefault` will intercept the default action